# Flat REST API (No nested relationship)

Tags: rest, api, normalization, normalizr

**Off-topic / Duplicate**

- [Many asynchronous calls vs single call to the API](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305872/many--asynchronous-calls-vs-single-call-to-the-api)
- [Many small requests vs. few large requests (API Design)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274340/many-small-requests-vs-few-large-requests-api-design)
- [REST API Design: Multiple calls vs. single call to the API](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341872/rest-api-design-multiple-calls-vs-single-call-to-the-api)

**ORIGINAL**

Is it a good idea?

For example:

```
// http://example.org/api/posts

[
  {
    "title": "Title one",
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Title two",
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Title three",
    "user_id": 2
  }
]
```

And then make another request:

```
// http://example.org/api/users?filters={ids: [1, 2, ...]}

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Vanessa"
  }
]
```

**PROs**

1. Simple REST API design (flat)
2. Simpler client-side code (no [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) / already "normalized")
3. Less overhead *per endpoint* on server (no need to load relationships)
4. No "duplicate" HTTP resource loaded between different endpoints (inevitable)
5. No repeated entities data inside a given endpoint response (smaller payload) – Ex: Above, `user = 1` (John) nested data would appear twice in `/posts` response

**CONs**

1. More HTTP requests to server – Although this could be alleviated with a good (and easier) cache strategy
2. GraphQL (newer tech) does not promote flat responses

*Note*:
A mix of the 2 approaches could also be considered.

**QUESTION**

Is it really that bad to hit the server with many more requests VS less requests BUT higher payload responses?

Comment: What's the question here. It sounds like you answered your own question?

Comment: Edited – Added question

Comment: Found multiple answers/opinions on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com